# What can I use to generate a not guessable url for each user?

Tags: url, encryption, hash, bcrypt

I am working on a project that will have users and profile images. I need to save these images in a folder and be able to receive the image from knowing the user ID.

I'm picturing something like `/images/profiles/{hash of user ID here}.png`
The user ID will be an integer, e.g 52 or 495

- What is the standards used for hashing urls?
- Is it safe to use `password_hash` from `bcrypt` for this purpose?
- What other alternatives do I have?

Comment: Why do you want to obfuscate it? Just use the user ID.

Comment: Users aren't necessarily publicly available. If I don't obfuscate it their profile pictures become publicly available. Not sure why I have to justify this.

Comment: Not asking you to justify anything. The picture is going to be publicly available if it has a URL regardless of what you do with the name. Regardless, something simply like a MD5 hash of the user ID would be enough. You aren't really trying to protect anything just make it less obvious.

Comment: I basically wan't it to be practically impossible for users to guess urls. As far as i can see MD5 is cryptographically broken, and I'm guessing it's fairly easy to spot if it's being used.

Comment: As it is a one-way hash and you aren't going to have duplicate user IDs even if someone knows it is a MD5 hash the idea that someone might try to "hack" it to figure out a user ID to retrieve a picture doesn't make sense. You could simply use a date stamp with microseconds and random characters from the persons name if you didn't want it to be obvious that it was a MD5 hash or a password_hash hash.

Comment: You can use any one way hash (like md5, sha1, ...) with some random information (like the CPU micro time, username, ...) which would generate random hashes [if you store the path in db] or some secret key concatenated into your user ID that would generate a unique re-producable hash for each user.

Comment: The stakes here are incredibly low in that if someone breaks the hash they can get a user's profile picture. Use something simple and fast like SHA1. You could salt it if you want to prevent someone from just iterating through all the IDs if they ever figure it out, but that extra complexity and, again, incredibly low stakes.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a sequential number, you should generate a Universal Unique Id (UUID) and use that to identify a user. The UUID can then also become part of the URL you are using.

I would suggest [UUIDv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) in your case, which will contain 122 Bits of randomness. Since your user ids should not be publicly available or guessable, you have to make sure that the UUID generator you are using is backed by a secure random number generator.

If 122 Bits of randomness is not sufficiently secure for your needs, just generate some random data of sufficient length, using a secure random number generator, and convert that to hex.

**BUT** in case you have to be able to control who accesses the information stored for a user, you are on the wrong path. In this case you won't get around implementing a authentication / authorization layer.

Comment: The correct solution to problem X given OP's stated problem Y. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: 122 bits of randomness is sufficiently secure, period. Even if you generate 2^58 UUID's then you still only have around a 1 in 2^64 chance of duplicating a single one.